# How to make a Horizontal and vertical scrolling TableView in iOS using storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift

[here is my design structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOVVP.jpg)
I was wondering about creating a horizontal and vertical scrolling tableview. I have tried a tableview inside a scrollview but I failed miserably. What to do?
I use swift4 but I wanted to do in storyboard.

The nature of content is like an excel sheet with lots of horizontal and vertical scrolling rows and columns of data.

Comment: Have you tried using collection view for this, they support both scrollings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can do this using a hack. Put the tableView inside a scrollView. Then you should give a dynamic width to the tableView by specifying a width in storyboard for tableView or any child view of that scrollView(So we get the horizontal scrolling).You have to adjust some constraints depending on your requirement

Mine worked fine but as many users have said try a collection View if its easy

Note. There is a default scrollView within a tableView, So adjust your height of tableView in a way so the scrollView of tableView work and not the parent scrollView, while scrolling from top to bottom

[image]

Comment: ok this worked for me.. what I did was I set a view1 inside my scrollview then inside the view1 I added tableview.. I set view1 height same as tableview height and view width I made it a constant 50 (just to make it less than table view's width) now.. I obtained the desired result.. i.e. scroll horizontal table view and a normal vertical scrolling table view..I actually designed it in freeform size so my width is 1000 for tableview. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using TableView try using collection view, there you can use horizontal and vertical scrolling using storyboard?

Comment: its a table view like details its just the heading or width part has so many values to show.. its like an invoice page with lots of horizontal columns and vertical rows.. like an excel sheet..

Comment: you can add collection view in a tableview and use that.

Comment: but that will make individual row scrolling horizontally right?

Comment: if you want you can have single or multiple row scrollable. it depends on your design. if you could share me the design I could suggest the best way.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOVVP.jpg here is my image.. its a continuous image this will be scrolling down as more data arrives as well as scrolling horizontally.. say 40 values down and 12 values to right

Comment: You can have table view inside of a collection view. in this way you won't have to worry about the vertical scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use collectionview instead of tableview.

If your requirement demands use of tableview anyhow, then you can use tableview within scrollview.

**In tableview within scrollview approach, you need to distinguish your parent scrollview as well as tableview's scrollview. Try to differentiate parent scrollview and tableview's scrollview with different tags. Because both scrollview will call delegate methods of viewcontroller, if implemented. Just check tag of scrollview in all delegate methods of scrollview and perform action accordingly.**

Answer (score 0):

As per my understaing you want a view which you want vertical scroll view and horizontal inside it.

So here my suggestion is to use **UITABLEVIEW** for vertical scrolling and **UICOLLECTIONVIEW** for horizontal scrolling inside tableview

Both will work fine